# explain why this code works the way it does

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, stdout, stdin

I have a following nodejs code

```
process.stdin.on('data', buffer => process.stdout.write(buffer.toString('utf8')))
```

I'm listening for input on stdin, and once i receive something, i write it to standard output

the output of this program is as follows
[image: output]

it works exactly as i expected it to work, i receive data from standard input, and write it to standard output, i assume that terminal program listens for current process standard output and once it receives new data, it displays it on my screen into the console (correct me if i'm wrong)

now consider this

```
process.stdout.on('data', buffer => process.stdin.write(buffer.toString('utf8')))
```

program works the same way, i can't understand why, in this case i'm listening for standard output, and once i receive a data i write it to standard input

what am i missing?